# screen.lockOrientation is not a function

Tags: javascript, mobile, responsive

I would like to use the API screen in Js with chrome.

```
 if ( navigator.userAgent.match( /(android|iphone)/gi ) ) {
        if ( 'orientation' in screen ) {
            //console.log( '// API supported, yeah!' );
            //console.log( 'new orientation is ', screen.orientation );
            screen.lockOrientation( 'landscape' );
        } else {
            console.log( '// API not supported ' );
        }
    } else {
        //alert('none');
    }
```

my error js : 
caught TypeError: screen.lockOrientation is not a function

/***  other ***/

```
if ( navigator.userAgent.match( /(android|iphone)/gi ) ) {
    if ( 'orientation' in screen ) {
        let locOrientation = screen.lockOrientation || screen.mozLockOrientation || screen.msLockOrientation;
        locOrientation('landscape');
        console.log( '// API supported, yeah!' , locOrientation);
        console.log( 'new orientation is ', screen.orientation );
        //screen.lockOrientation( 'landscape' );
    } else {
        console.log( '// API not supported ' );
    }
} else {
    //alert('none');
}
```

my error js :  locOrientation is not a function

update : 20/04/2017  ->   With Javascript, we can't lock orientation with the navigator.

Comment: is this for a normal page or an app?

Comment: a simple webpage, my setup : ( webpack, vuejs )

Comment: it's not for pages...

Answer (score 8):

This is because `lockOrientation` is still prefixed. See the [2] footnote in [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/lockOrientation#Browser_compatibility) MDN article. Also, in Chrome it is under `orientation.lock`. See the [1] footnote in the MDN article.

```
locOrientation = screen.lockOrientation || screen.mozLockOrientation || screen.msLockOrientation || screen.orientation.lock;
locOrientation('landscape');
```

Please note that not all browsers have this function. Please check if `locOrientation` is set before you use it.

**Edit:** Adding the newer `orientation.lock` to the example.

Comment: I have a prob with your source code , i update my post

Comment: Ah, Chrome has it under orientation.lock!

Comment: I prefer to force navigator to lock an orientation